# Polemic/controversial in noun form

Tags: grammar

what would you call the putting forward of a controversial debate?

i.e. something is polemic when controversial but you can't say 'i am developing a polemic' (that is, use polemic as a noun)

is there an equivalent noun that would fit the case?

Comment: [Polemic](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/polemic?q=polemic) is a noun.

Comment: As is controversy.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can use *[polemic](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/polemic)* as a noun. It **is** a noun. For example:

> Her book is a fierce polemic against the inequalities in our society.

You should do your research before making statements like that.